# Dual booting Ubuntu 16.04.1 alongside Windows 10 in such a way that Ubuntu can be able to access/read files of NTFS?

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, partitioning, ntfs

I want to **dual boot** my laptop (Ubuntu 16.04.1 LTS alongside Windows 10).
 How do I perform installation so that, after installing ubuntu, I should be **able to read**( files, videos, photos, etc) which are stored on Other drives( in NTFS format).
I have done dualbooting once with other laptop & I failed to do so.
*Now I want to access files that are on NTFS format* after Installation?

I know how to Install ubuntu on a windows machine. I just want such (as mentioned above) settings to do so.

Comment: First of all you should avoid that behavior. If you need shared data then use a NTFS partition other than the Windows system partition. And either way you'll have to disable fast startup in Windows 8 or newer (and shutdown Windows, not just reboot, to make it effective) because this new Windows default behavior hibernates all (Windows) partitions.

Comment: I had run a code in command prompt once in my old latop to hibernate windows os. I failed badly. I had to troubleshoot and refresh my Windows OS.

Comment: @Sparrow he is right...u might have done something wrong ..there is only one instruction to be run to turn off hibernation... just install Ubuntu the way u used to..as windows doesnt shut down u can access it using `sudo ntfsfix /dev/sdXY` and hibernated disks will be mounted..inorder to acess drive which windows is installed in ..best way is to turn off hibernation..thats it..do it..this time do proper hibernation turn off...(also can turn off using UI :in options of turn on fast startup)

Comment: I want a series of steps so as to avoid any risks.

Comment: See [this page](http://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/4189-fast-startup-turn-off-windows-10-a.html) and [this one](http://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/2859-hibernate-enable-disable-windows-10-a.html) for instructions on disabling Fast Startup and Hibernate in Windows.

Comment: @CelticWarrior see my answer to this question. Cheers, Al

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this easily, one of two different ways.

## Using your existing Windows partition

1. in Windows, go to the Power control panel and turn off **fast boot**.
2. in Windows, open an administrative command prompt window, type **powercfg /h off**.
3. in Ubuntu, click on the Windows icon that's in your Unity launcher, or, if you want it auto-mounted at boot time, modify your **/etc/fstab** with something like:

```
UUID=0C0F93CE58153D42 /media/your_username/Windows ntfs-3g defaults 0 0
```

change **your_username**, and change the **UUID** with the correct one found by using the **sudo blkid** command in terminal.

## Using a new Shared_Data partition

1. Using gparted, or Windows own Disk Management application, create a new NTFS partition called Shared_Data.
2. Edit your /etc/fstab to include something like:

```
UUID=0C0F93CE58153D42 /media/your_username/Shared_Data ntfs-3g defaults 0 0
```

change **your_username**, and change the **UUID** with the correct one found by using the **sudo blkid** command in terminal.

Comment: Will the problem be solved if I just turn off fast boot?

Comment: If you dual-boot Windows and Ubuntu, you should do both... disable fast boot and disable hibernation. Cheers, Al

Comment: Is this (powercfg /h off) for hibernation.

Comment: Yes. Cheers, Al